# Spring Boot 1.2.1.RELEASE and JNDI Errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jndi

I receive an error when I deploy my web application, using IntelliJ 14.0, to a local Apache Tomcat instance. I am using Spring Boot 1.2.1.RELEASE and with a JNDI connection.

The contents of my application.yaml file looks like this:

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: production

---

spring:
    profiles: development
        datasource:
        platform: h2

---

spring:
    profiles: production
        datasource:
            jndi-name: java:/comp/env/jdbc/teams
            platform: mysql
    jpa:
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: create-drop
```

My configuration file, Application.java, looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

I am using Apache Tomcat 8.0.15 and have configured a JNDI connection in the context.xml file.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/teams" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="***" password="***" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teams"/>
```

I am using IntelliJ 14.0 to deploy my application locally to Apache Tomcat using the production profile.

The error I receive when when I attempt to deploy the application is as follows:

org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@4f83492a] with key 'dataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: Catalina:type=DataSource,host=localhost,context=/project,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/teams"

What could be wrong with the way the application is configured?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace please? I think you may be able to work around the problem by setting `spring.jmx.enabled` to `false`

Comment: Here it is: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:4ae8

Comment: I modified the application.yaml file and it is now working. I added spring.jmx.enabled and spring.jpa.database-platform properties.

spring:
    profiles:
        active: production

---

spring:
    profiles: development
    datasource:
        platform: h2


---

spring:
    profiles: production
    datasource:
        jndi-name: java:/comp/env/jdbc/teams
        platform: mysql
    jpa:
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: create-drop
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    jmx:
        enabled: false

Answer (score 0):

I modified the application.yaml file and the application is now working. I added spring.jmx.enabled and spring.jpa.database-platform properties to the application.yaml file.

spring:
    profiles:
        active: production

---

spring:
    profiles: development
    datasource:
        platform: h2

---

spring:
    profiles: production
    datasource:
        jndi-name: java:/comp/env/jdbc/teams
        platform: mysql
    jpa:
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: create-drop
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    jmx:
        enabled: false